# What happens if I implement `MaxEncodedLen` lower than the actual max length?

Tags: runtime

What is the consequence if I implement `MaxEncodedLen` lower than the actual max length of the type? Will the bytes which are above the length just not be written to storage?

Answer (score 4):

`MaxEncodedLen` is used for weight estimation, so the problem you face here will be the same as if you "under-weigh" your extrinsics.

When producing a block, the weight stuff ensures that your block is not "too big". If you put a `MaxEncodedLen` smaller than the actual encoded length, you may produce blocks which are bigger than allowed, and thus will be rejected by the Relay Chain. If these blocks can be generated by users, then a user could attack your network by filling your chain full of under-length extrinsics, and basically force all the nodes on your network to waste a bunch of computation building blocks which are invalid.

> Will the bytes which are above the length just not be written to storage?

No, the storage will still be written, and we don't check `MaxEncodedLen` when writing to storage. For some types like `BoundedVec`, there is special decoding logic which will return an error decoding storage where the vector is bigger than the expected bound, but this is programmed specifically for this type.